# Android SingleTask onResume persist state

Tags: java, android, mobile, state

I have this Android application where I am using branch.io for deeplinking and it works best when the the app has only one instance so I am using android:launchMode="singleTask"

My problem is when I background the app, it always clear all my memory and it is annoying because I don't want all the memory to be cleared.

Is there a way for us to have singleTask and also not have all the app's memory cleared when we go from background to foreground?

Comment: What makes you think that "all my memory is cleared" when you background the app? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're running into is that having android:launchMode="singleTask" means that specific deep-linked activity is the [*start* of the activity stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode), and is a single instance, so when you get deep-linked through AppLinks, this gets invoked first.

In case you want to use singleTask, have it be on an Activity that acts as a "SplashActivity", or a BaseActivity that all deep-linked activities inherit from, that can handle being a single activity, and can drive users to the actual deep-linked Activity you need to reach.

Then, whenever the app is taken to the background, the BaseActivity will be notified of onStop and you can save your work there.